# Add attributes to existing object at same time

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have this simple object:

```
var User = {
    name: 'Hans',
    get_name: function(){return this.name},

    street: 'Kings',
    postcode: '482932',
    city: 'New York'
}
```

For a better overview, I would like to do something like this:

```
var User = {
    name: 'Hans',
    get_name: function(){return this.name},
};

//Adress Information
User.add({
    street: 'Kings',
    postcode: '482932',
    city: 'New York'
});
```

As expected this doesn´t work. To achieve somthing similar I could write:

```
User.street = 'Kings';
User.postcode = '482932';
.......
```

But I would like to add several attributes at the same time. Is there a handy function for it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) (this will overwrite existing properties):

```
Object.assign(User, { /* some new props */ });
```

Using [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#merge) (this won't overwrite existing properties):

```
_.extend(User, { /* some new props */ });
```

In ES5 by adding a method to User:

```
User.add = function(newProps) {
  Object.keys(newProps).forEach(function(prop) {
    this[prop] = newProps[prop];
  }.bind(this));
};
```

Really, the `add` method should go in the `User.prototype` if you want to follow OO "principles".

Comment: Thanks @JoshBeam  `Object.assign`, really will help me to keep my code clean!

Comment: @JohnSmith, no problem. Keep in mind, it's an ECMAScript6 method, so you'll need an environment that supports it (such as Node harmony, or by using something like Babel to compile ES6 into ES5)

Answer (score 1):

One solution :

```
var User = {
    name: 'Hans',
    get_name: function(){return this.name},
};
User.add = function(obj){
  var me = this;
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(o){
    if(! me[o] ) me[o] = obj[o];
  })
}
//Adress Information
User.add({
    street: 'Kings',
    postcode: '482932',
    city: 'New York'
});

console.dir(User)
/*
    name        "Hans"
    get_name    function()
    add         function(obj)
    street      "Kings"
    postcode    "482932"
    city        "New York"
*/
```

```js
    var User = {
        name: 'Hans',
        get_name: function(){return this.name},
    };

    User.add = function(obj){
      var me = this;
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(o){
        if(! me[o] ) me[o] = obj[o];
      })
      return this;
    }
    //Adress Information
    User.add({
        street: 'Kings',
        postcode: '482932',
        city: 'New York'
    });

    console.dir(User);
    /*
        name        "Hans"
        get_name    function()
        add         function(obj)
        street      "Kings"
        postcode    "482932"
        city        "New York"
    */

    document.getElementById('el').innerHTML = '<pre>'+JSON.stringify(User , null , ' ')+'</pre>';
```

```html
<div id='el'><div>
```